# Apply Visitor Pattern as an Extensibilty Mechanism for a single class

Tags: uml, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Let's say in my program I have a class called `Robot` that inherits from some other class.

Until now I have some methods inside `Robot` like `addPart` or `getCost`. Now I'm asked to add a new module of functionality to it (a few methods that use it's parts) but they explicitly ask the new module to be added with little to no impact to the current class.

I thought a `Visitor` could solve this but the thing is I won't be applying the pattern to a hierarchy. Is this a correct thing to do? (as you can see my `Robot` is part of a composite)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, I agree with your approach. You have successfully identified an approach that allows you to extend Robot (a parts composite) without having to actually modify the Robot class. The only changes I would make are the following:

I would introduce a new interface named something like **IPartsComposite** that would define the **Accept** method. This interface would be implemented by **Robot** since it is composed of **Part** instances.

The base Visitor would be a base generic class or interface i.e.**Visitor<T>**. This type would define a single method **Visit(T)**. Then, in your case, you would have three concrete implementations of **Visitor<IPartsComposite>**.

- PartsVisitorService
- PartsVisitorCosts
- PartsVisitorProduction

In each of these concrete classes you would implement **Visit(IPartsComposite)**.

Comment: Actually I think I have a problem now with this approach. Every Visit function should return something different so I don't know if this pattern is now viable for this.

Comment: @user2313248 Well you could change the signature of Visit to return a generic Result object. A Result could wrap each of the different return types.